# Why to use stopImmediatePropagation() in a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form named **frm_contact** and I need to bind submit event of that form. The "problem" (or better...the doubt) is that if I DON'T use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` the submit event is called many times. I fixed it using `stopImmediatePropagation()` function.

I bind the event in this manner:

```
$('#frm_contact').live("submit", function(e){  
});
```

I'm using `live()`, why do I need to use stopImmediatePropagation() ?

Comment: How do you trigger the `submit` event?

Comment: Could it be that you bind the event handler several times? That would be the only explanation for why the handler is called multiple times.

Comment: Felix, I load with .html() the form, but I'm using .live() so why that problem?

Comment: Are u really using `$('frm_contact')` as the selector? It doesnt seems to be valid for me.

Comment: @Quincy, what? wy is not valid for you? i have <form id="frm_contact"> ... </form>

Comment: @Quincy, i forgot # (here)...i just edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you saying that your script isn't working, or asking what `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` means...

either way, here is a excerpt of what it means:

> In addition to keeping any additional handlers on an element from
>   being executed, this method also stops the bubbling by implicitly
>   calling `event.stopPropagation()`. To simply prevent the event from
>   bubbling to ancestor elements but allow other event handlers to
>   execute on the same element, we can use `event.stopPropagation()`
>   instead.
>
> Use `event.isImmediatePropagationStopped()` to know whether this
>   method was ever called (on that event object).

More info just google first  :)

but here it is:
http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Comment: Since the .live() method handles events once they have propagated to the top of the document, it is not possible to stop propagation of live events.